# How to inject script to all frames matching URL from browser extension background-script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

In our browser extension background-script we have a code that injects content-script to all tabs matching specific URL. It is used to activate extension after it is installed without need to reload matching page(s):

```
chrome.tabs.query({
  status: 'complete',
  url: 'https://*.example.com/*'
}, function (tabs) {
  tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
      file: 'content-script.js',
      runAt: 'document_idle'
    });
  });
});
```

Is there a way to inject content-script also to all frames matching this URL? Eg. if somebody has our webapp (app.example.com) embedded in his page (www.acme.com). We need to do it without any additional extension permissions (now they are `desktopCapture` and `https://*.example.com/`) or without mentioning www.acme.com anywhere in our extension. Otherwise we would use webNavigation API.

Comment: Use chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames. Alternatively, Chrome has [declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) API.

Comment: @wOxxOm chrome.webNavigation unfortunately needs a permission. declarativeContent uses page actions and I see there none that could inject a script.

Comment: declarativeContent can inject content scripts.